# ASP.NET MVC 3 beta: TryUpdateModel throws NullreferenceException in unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-3

Since I updated to ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta 1, I get a `NullReferenceException` whenever I call `TryUpdateModel()` during a unit test session.

The stack trace looks like this:

> Execute
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.<>c_*DisplayClassc.b*_7(ValueProviderFactory factory)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider()
>      at Zeiterfassung.Controllers.ControllerBase`1.TryUpdateModelAndTrackChanges[TModel](TModel model, String prefix) in C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\Sites\Zeiterfassung\Zeiterfassung\Controllers\ControllerBase.cs:line 164
>   ... My own code from here on...

The same action method works fine when running on the web server, so my guess is that it is a problem with Dependency Injection in unit testing.

Is there something I need to setup for this to work? I'd rather not revert to the previous ASP.NET MVC version if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mock the ControllerContext. Personally I use [MvcContrib.TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) which is based on [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) to achieve this:

```
// arrange
var controller = new HomeController();
new TestControllerBuilder().InitializeController(controller);

// act
var actual = controller.Index();
```

but any mocking framework could do the job. You just need to make sure that in your unit test `controller.ControllerContext` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

If using Rhino Mocks alone (without MvcContrib.TestHelper), try the following:

```
controller = new HomeController(repository);
controller.ControllerContext = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ControllerContext>();
```

Personally, I actually create a Test Class level variable:

```
private HomeController controller;
```

Then for each test I re-initialize this variable:

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
    controller = new HomeController();
    controller.ControllerContext = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ControllerContext>();
}
```